# Merge two arrays as if shuffling cards without iterating?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, is there an easy way to merge 2 arrays as if shuffling a deck of cards?

For example:

[ "1", "2", "3" ] + 
[ "a", "b", "c" ]

=> [ "1", "a", "2", "b", "3", "c" ]

Comment: best you can get without looping is `a.concat(b)` i think

Comment: That won't shuffle it though, like his example specifies. I doubt there is a clean way to do it without iterating

Comment: @ThomasWood i said best you can get, you cant shuffle without a loop

Comment: sure, you can use recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This action is typically called "[zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_%28computer_science%29)".

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) has an [implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/08d88b33359b26996fc06f5cc6bf84b4a7afe2d3/underscore.js#L515) of it:

```
var a1 = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
var a2 = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
var zipped = _.zip(a1, a2);
```

If you want a *random* order, you can use [`shuffle`](http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle):

```
var shuffled = _.shuffle(a1.concat(a2));
```

Comment: That still implements an iteration, though.

Comment: thats a loop too, this is kind of a stupid question since even if javascript did have a function like that, it would still be a loop behind the scenes

Comment: Of course there is a loop `:)`. I pointed the OP to a working, well tested tool, which I expect will be readable to most programmers.

Comment: Dear downvoter - the question is not a riddle, not code golf, and isn't looking for clever solutions. The OP wanted to perform a common operation on two arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var arr2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

You can just loop through the arrays and create a new one. This example assumes that `arr1` and `arr2` are the same length.

```
var result = (function(a, b){
  for(var i = 0, result = []; i < a.length; i++)
    result.push(a[i], b[i]);
  return result;
})(arr1, arr2);

// result == ["1", "a", "2", "b", "3", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without iterating, but you can hide the iteration behind some array functions.

```
var a = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
var b = [ "a", "b", "c" ];

// only works if a and b have the same length
var c = a.concat(b).map(function(item, index, arr){
  return index % 2 ? arr[arr.length/2 + (index+1)/2 - 1] : arr[index/2];
});

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a closure that can be used as an array for reading (i.e. `c(i)` returns `i`-th element of result):

```
c = function(i){ return [a, b][i & 1][i >> 1]; };
```

or, probably more efficient, as

```
c = function(i){ return (i & 1) ? b[i >> 1] : a[i >> 1]; };
```

The nice thing of this approach is that you don't build all elements at once, but you will just get the element from the original arrays only if requested.

This also allows using functions instead of arrays for `a` and `b`:

```
c = function(i){ return (i & 1) ? b(i >> 1) : a(i >> 1); };
```